# How to do a proper Template binding?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, templatebinding

I seem to have become a bit rusty on template bindings, I just can't get this to work. Do you see what's wrong?

I have a custom control like this:

```
public class TextPropertyRow : HeaderedContentControl
{
}
```

With a style and control template like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Framework:TextPropertyRow}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Framework:TextPropertyRow}">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" />
          <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="2" />
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Which I'm using like this:

```
<Framework:TextPropertyRow Header="Value"
  Content="{Binding PublicStringPropertyOnDataContext}" />
```

But values entered into the textbox won't get injected into the viewmodel datacontext. Is this not the correct way of doing it?

Comment: TemplateBinding cannot be TwoWay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cases where the value is going both ways at runtime, you want to do a regular Binding with `RelativeSource TemplatedParent`

```
<TextBox 
    Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
    Grid.Column="2"
    />
```

Comment: Oh man, forgot about that. I like XAML but WPF is annoying =)

Comment: @AndreasZita Yeah, that one gets me every week or two.